# Pass array function into user defined function

Tags: vba, excel, unique

I have a standard user defined function that concationates all the unique values. What I am trying to do is to perform this function on a range that satisfies a condition.

```
Function ConcatUniq(xRg As Range, xChar As String) As String
'updateby Extendoffice 20151228
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xDic As Object
    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xDic(xCell.Value) = Empty
    Next
    ConcatUniq = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)
    Set xDic = Nothing
End Function
```

Lets make an example:
If we have the following data:

```
A1:A5 = {1,2,2,4,1}

B1:B5 = {"group1", "group1","group1", "group2", "group2"}

C1 = "group1"
```

Now I want to find the unique values using the ConcatUniq function for all numbers that are in group1. Usually, if I want to perform another function for example the median I would do the following:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(B1:B5=C1,A1:A5))
```

Activate it using cntrl shift enter which gives 2 (create an array function from it).
For some reasons this does not work in combination with a user defined function.

```
=ConcatUniq(IF(B1:B5=C1,A1:A5)," ")
```

Desired result:

```
1 2
```

Does someone know how I could fix this problem?

Comment: The output of this `IF(B1:B5=C1,A1:A5)," ` is NOT one of these :`xRg As Range`, so use Variant and test for both Range and Array/Variant and then go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Public Function ConcatUniq(ByVal rangeOrArray As Variant, ByVal xChar As String) As String

    Dim generalArray As Variant
    If IsArray(rangeOrArray) Then
        'operate on it as if was an array
        generalArray = rangeOrArray
    Else
        If TypeName(rangeOrArray) = "Range" Then
            'operate on it as if was a Range
            If rangeOrArray.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                generalArray = rangeOrArray.Value
            Else
                generalArray = Array(rangeOrArray.Value)
            End If
        Else
            'Try to process as if it was a derivative of a value of a single cell range.....
            generalArray = Array(rangeOrArray)
        End If
    End If

    Dim xDic As Object
    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim xCell As Variant
    For Each xCell In generalArray
        If xCell <> False Then xDic(xCell) = Empty  ' EDIT - HACKY....
    Next
    ConcatUniq = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)

End Function
```

You can see that that whole block of if-elses can be factored out to be a separate function to transform worksheet input to a unified form for operating on values of a worksheet.

Comment: This almost works, but this also adds the value FALSE to the list so this outputs 1 2 FALSE

Comment: Well if False is being passed in, then you may want to cut it out in the UDF as per my edit in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ParamArray` to accommodate array returned from Excel's array formula. As ParamArray should always be the last one, so your method signature will change.

---

This will work with `=ConcatUniq(" ",IF(B1:B5=C1,A1:A5))` on CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

```
Public Function ConcatUniq(xChar As String, ParamArray args())

    Dim xDic As Object
    Dim xVal

    Set xDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each xVal In args(0)
        If Not Not xVal Then
        xDic(xVal) = Empty
        End If
    Next

    ConcatUniq = Join$(xDic.Keys, xChar)

End Function
```

Comment: I still think MacroMan's comment should be taken into account to accommodate all data entry type.

Comment: What L42 says, this only works if there are numbers in A1:A5

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be to introduce an additional function. This function would take care of the condition and would generate an array consisting only of data fulfilling the condition. 
Try something like this:

```
 function condition_check(data1() as integer, data2() as string, condition_value as string) as integer
        number_of_elements = Ubound(data1)
        j = 0
        for i = 0 to number_of_elements
            if data2(i) = condition_value then
               condition_check(j) = data1(i)
               j = j+1
            end if
        next i
end function
```